# Projection issue

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, landsat-7

[image]

The Landsat data having a subset area when I try to open in QGIS it is locating on top of sea. See in picture

Comment: if you are using Google Maps you should set the project CRS to EPSG:3857 (Pseudo Web Mercator)

Comment: actually i have vector layer for the same area and that is not overlay on top of this dataset......and this is not the first time i am getting this issue earlier also i faced the same issue...if you have any idea please help

Comment: My guess is that the subsetted data has lost its coordinate reference system (CRS) or its georeferencing or both. What extent does the subset layer have? What is its CRS?